# OpenLDAP - return value of UID using only ldapsearch

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'd like `ldapsearch` to return only the value of the UID of a user based on a specified mail address. I can make it work with the following query:

```sh
ldapsearch -H ldap://localhost -w '...' -D "cn...com" -b  "ou...com" mail=... -LLL uid | grep 'uid:' | cut -d ' ' -f2-
```

This gives the desired result, but requires 2 other Linux commands.

If I remove the Linux commands, the output is:

```sh
dn: uid=...,ou=...
uid: ...
```

**Q:** Is it possible to retrieve the UID value based on a mail address, with only using command `ldapsearch`?

Note, I do **not** like to add arguments `-tt`, since that will write the variable to a file, which is undesired.

Comment: The [man page for `ldapsearh`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ldapsearch) doesn't show any option that would allow that. Why do you need it? There might be another way to do what you want.

Comment: Yeah exactly, that's what I thought. The reason is simply because I thought it might be possible, I'm not totally in favor of mixing Linux commands with other commands, if there's a cleaner approach.